# Type Object does not support slicing Unity3D

Tags: unity

I am getting the following error in my code and I can't seem to understand why. Can anyone help me with it?

This is my current code. The line causing the error is marked in a comment near the end.

```
var rows : int = 4;
var cols : int = 4;
var totalCards : int = cols * rows;
var matchesNeedToWin : int = totalCards * 0.5; 
var matchesMade : int = 0;

var cardW : int = 100;
var cardH : int = 100;

var aCards : Array; 
var aGrid : Array;

// This Array will store the two cards that the player flipped
var aCardsFlipped : ArrayList; 

// To prevent player from clicking buttons when we don't want him to
var playerCanClick : boolean; 

var playerHasWon : boolean = false;     


class Card extends System.Object {
var isFaceUp : boolean = false;
var isMatched : boolean = false;
var img : String;

    function Card () {
        img = "robot";
    }
}

function Start () {

    var i : int = 0;
    var j : int = 0;

    playerCanClick = true;
    aCards = new Array ();
    aGrid = new Array ();
    aCardsFlipped = new ArrayList ();

    for ( i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
        aGrid [i] = new Array ();

            for (j = 0; j < cols; cols++ ) {
            aGrid [i] [j] = new Card (); // <------ Error over here
        }
    }
}


function Update () {
    Debug.Log("Game Screen has loaded");
}
```

The error states as follows:

> **Error BCE0048: Type 'Object' does not support slicing. (BCE0048)** (Assembly-UnityScript)

Comment: Please comment `#pragma strict` Hope this helps

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like Jonathan Hobbs said, I've made a few changes. 
This is what I modified those code

```
var aCards:Array
var aGrid:Card[,]; //<-- change how you declare this variable to multidimensional arrays
var aCardsFlipped:ArrayList;
```

And change this in the Start function

```
function Start () {
    playerCanClick = true; 
    aCards = new Array();
    aGrid = new Card[rows,cols]; //<-- I instantiate it as rows*cols array
    aCardsFlipped = new ArrayList();
    for (var i=0;i<rows;i++)
    {
        for (var j=0;j<cols;j++)
        {
            aGrid[i,j] = new Card(); //<-- Then assign the value like this
        }
    }
}
```

Hope this help

Comment: I would upvote your answer if you actually made it clear what you changed. Others with the same problem (but different code) will come to this site for a solution, so a good answer would let _them_ know what's going on, too, so they can fix it for themselves (since copying+pasting the code above would do nothing for them, and it contains no value to their situation unless they dive in and try to find out what you changed).

Answer (score 4):

Javascript doesn't support multidimensional arrays well, so either switch to storing an array of objects or switch to C# in order to use multidimensional arrays.

This advice came up in answers to [this Unity question](http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/10877/type-object-does-not-support-slicing-array-help.html). Meanwhile, according to [this other question](http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/11963/how-to-create-multidimensional-arrays-in-javascrip.html), you can declare them like this:

```
var a : float[,];
```

Or in your case, I'm guessing the syntax would be this (with or without the `new`, I'm not sure):

```
aGrid = new Card[,];
```

#### So instead of your problematic line you'd have this:

```
aGrid[i,j] = new Card();
```

If you really do want to use a jagged array you need to use a workaround (according to that first link): use the `Array.Add()` method rather than directly setting the variable at each index.

Comment: +1 for a good answer that was probably used without acceptance.

Comment: well this answer omits a couple crucial facts (which I'm editing in) so vish may not have gotten this working

Comment: @jhocking What were the omitted crucial facts? If it's the poor native support for multidimensional arrays, that's true - just not in Unity's version of it, which supports multidimensional arrays just fine. They're used right there in the post - that's native JavaScript code in Unity, if I understand correctly.

Comment: oh I didn't notice the dates on the responses on those links; apparently this used to be an issue (as in a couple years ago) but it's since changed. I'm not going to edit the post back because I seem to be a little mistaken here, but maybe add a note that the information in the first link is dated so that can cause confusion